# How to pass a variable dynamically to a URL in playwright page.goto function?

Tags: python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test

I want to pass a variable in the URL, here is my code:

```
   url_id = ["253443","456545"]
   for id in url_id :
       print("Inside For loop", id) # this print the correct id (253443)
       page.goto('https://abc.name.co/admin/{id}/reports/stats',timeout=0)
```

But when I printed the URL it came like this:
'https://abc.name.co/admin/7Bid%7/reports/stats'
like this in the {} block -> "%7Bid%7D"

Can you please review my approach and let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, so to embed the string value from the array you have to use the [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), something like this:

```py
url_id = ["253443", "456545"]
for id in url_id:
    print("Inside For loop", id)  # this print the correct id (253443)
    page.goto(f"https://abc.name.co/admin/{id}/reports/stats", timeout=0)
```

Comment: wow thank you Alapan Das . It really works :)